# Error when using useFieldArray append with react-hook-form (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus'))

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I got error from Material-UI `Select` component (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')) when I try to call append function from `useFieldArray` hook.

Codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-h248x?file=/src/index.js).

Click "Append" button you will see the error page. Please help me to investigate this problem or suggestion best practice for this code.

PS. Try to change name on `line: 18` to `name: "test2"` then Click "Append" again it not error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `onFocus` to please `react-hook-form` when it wants to focus the input. See the `onFocus` prop of `Controller` [here](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#Controller). Note that this prop was [removed](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/3853#issuecomment-756406024) in RHF v7.

```
<Controller
  render={({ ref, ...rest }) => (...)}
  name={name}
  onFocus={() => {
    const inputEl = document.querySelector(
      `input[name="${name}"]`
    );
    inputEl.focus();
  }}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm not fully understand the root cause why this error only happen when work with useFieldArray?

Comment: @GotzJi tbf I'm not either. I'm not using `useFieldArray` very much and I'm using RHF v7 now.

Comment: I would like to try v7 soon but at moment my current project use v6, so I don't want to change it. thanks for your help again